# Restriciton in combobox should not delete text in combox

Tags: vb.net

Combobox should not accept any inputs and backspace. My code accepts backspace.

```
 Private Sub ComboBox5_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles ComboBox5.KeyPress

    If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 13 And Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 And Not IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) Or IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) Then

        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't be easier just to allow `Enter`, rather than restricting everything else?

Comment: Your `If`-statement is redundant and hard to understand. What key presses are you really looking to allow/block? FWIW it is your `Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8` check that allows backspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description and the code you posted don't match well. I am going to assume you left some words out, and you actually want to allow CR, BKSP, and any numeric. It looks like you want a numbers only ComboBox.

As Vincent said, your If statement is confusing.  "Not IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) Or IsNumeric(e.KeyChar)" evaluates always as true, it's basically A or Not A.

For numbers only in ComboBoxes, I like this method, though there are lots of ways to skin that cat:

```
Private Sub ComboBox5_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles ComboBox5.KeyPress
    Select Case AscW(e.KeyChar)
        Case 13
            'Do whatever you need with CR here

        Case 8,     3,   22,   24, 26
            'backsp copy paste cut undo
            'let 'em be

        Case Else
            e.Handled = Not IsNumeric(e.KeyChar)

    End Select
End Sub
```

If you really didn't want BackSpace, simply delete 8 from that case statement, or the whole case statement if you don't want the user to edit the text at all.

Comment: To improve readability and "modifyability" you can substitute all `Chr()` calls with a single `AscW()` call instead: `Select Case AscW(e.KeyChar)` and then: `Case 3, 8, 22, 24, 26` (etc.)

Comment: I edited the comment as I remembered that `Chr(<constant number>)` will also be compiled into a constant char. Though it is harder to read with all those calls. ;)

Comment: Thanks! It's more readable to use constants with names that make sense, but I didn't take the time to add my constants to this answer.

Comment: I didn't mean that you should add constants, if that's what you thought. I just meant that calling the `Chr()` function with a constant number (ex. `Chr(3)`) will cause the compiler to compile it into an actual constant character (the character with a char code of `3`) instead of always making a procedure call. But yes, adding constants like `Const Backspace = 8` makes it even more readable, but it's not what I meant. ;)

Comment: I know that's not what you meant. That's what I meant though. I thought, but wasn't sure, I had read that chr(8) gets compiled as a constant. I use named constants for my own readability. I can't remember that 8 is backspace, and 3 certainly isn't copy as a character. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict your `comboBox` so that it should not accept inputs.

you can set the `DropDownStyle` property of your `ComboBox` to `DropDownList`

You can also set it programmatically

```
ComboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
```